# Fetch new selected sort data from P13n dialog

Tags: filtering, sapui5

As per the [sap.m.sample.P13nDialog](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/sample/sap.m.sample.P13nDialog/preview) example. The model is showing the correct data in the personalization dialog
[image]

But by clicking on handle OK I **don't see the current** but the initial sort items.
`products.json` model:

[image]

```
this.oPersonalizationDialog.getPanels()[1].getSortItems()
```

How can I get the current selected sort items?

only the initial sort colum is returned

```
console.log(oSortPanel.getAggregation("sortItems")[0]); // ok
```

a second sort colum is newer set in the "sortItems"

```
console.log(oSortPanel.getAggregation("sortItems")[1]); // undefined :/
```

[zip Example](http://www.mediafire.com/file/5ss7pqrtddkklc5/sap.m.sample.P13nDialog.zip/file)

added code

**Page.controller.js**

```
    oPersonalizationDialog: null,
    bShowResetEnabled: false,
    bIsReseted: false,

    handleOK: function(oEvent) {
        //this._storeShowResetEnabled();
        var oSortPanel = oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1];
        console.log(oSortPanel);
        var oSortItems = oSortPanel.getAggregation("sortItems")[0];
        console.log(oSortItems);
        var oItemsObject = {
            "ColumnKey": oSortItems.getColumnKey(),
            "Operation": oSortItems.getOperation()
        };
        console.log(oItemsObject);
        console.log(oSortPanel.getAggregation("sortItems")[1]); // undefined

        this.oPersonalizationDialog.close();
    },

    handleCancel: function(oEvent) {
        this.oPersonalizationDialog.close();
    },

    handleReset: function(oEvent) {
        this.bIsReseted = true;
        MessageToast.show("Reset button has been clicked", {
            width: "auto"
        });
    },

    onPersonalizationDialogPress: function(oEvent) {
        var oPersonalizationDialog = this._getDialog();

        oPersonalizationDialog.setShowResetEnabled(this.bShowResetEnabled);
        this.bIsReseted = false;

        oPersonalizationDialog.open();
    },

    onAddColumnsItem: function(oEvent) {
        MessageToast.show("Event 'addColumnsItem' fired in order to move the selected column item", {
            width: "auto"
        });
    },

    onChangeColumnsItem: function(oEvent) {
        MessageToast.show("Event 'changeColumnsItem' fired in order to move the selected column item", {
            width: "auto"
        });
    },

    _storeShowResetEnabled: function() {
        if (this.bIsReseted) {
            this.bShowResetEnabled = false;
        } else {
            this.bShowResetEnabled = this.oPersonalizationDialog.getShowResetEnabled();
        }
    },

    _getDialog: function() {
        if (this.oPersonalizationDialog) {
            return this.oPersonalizationDialog;
        }
        this.oPersonalizationDialog = sap.ui.xmlfragment("sap.m.sample.P13nDialog.PersonalizationDialog", this);

        this.getView().setModel(new JSONModel("products.json"));
        this.getView().setModel(new ResourceModel({
            bundleName: "sap.m.sample.P13nDialog.i18n.i18n"
        }), "i18n");

        this.getView().addDependent(this.oPersonalizationDialog);
        return this.oPersonalizationDialog;
    }
```

**view**

```
<mvc:View height="100%" controllerName="sap.m.sample.P13nDialog.Page"
xmlns:l="sap.ui.layout" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
xmlns="sap.m">
<l:VerticalLayout
    class="sapUiContentPadding"
    width="100%">
    <l:content>
        <Button
            text="Show Personalization Dialog"
            press="onPersonalizationDialogPress" />
    </l:content>
</l:VerticalLayout>
```

**PersonalizationDialog.fragment.xml.fragment** (Dialog)

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.m"
xmlns:core="sap.ui.core"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.sap.com/sapui5/extension/sap.ui.core.CustomData/1">
<P13nDialog ok="handleOK" cancel="handleCancel" showReset="true"
    reset="handleReset" initialVisiblePanelType="sort">
    <panels>
        <P13nColumnsPanel visible="true" addColumnsItem="onAddColumnsItem"
            changeColumnsItems="onChangeColumnsItem" type="columns"
            items="{
                path: '/ColumnCollection'
            }">
            <items>
                <!-- P13nItem columnKey="name" text="{i18n>ColumnName}" visible="true" 
                    / -->
                <P13nItem columnKey="{path}" text="{text}" visible="{visible}" />
            </items>
        </P13nColumnsPanel>
        <P13nSortPanel visible="false" type="sort"
            containerQuery="true"
            items="{
                path: '/ColumnCollection'
            }"
            sortItems="{
                path: '/SortItems'
            }">
            <P13nItem columnKey="{path}" text="{text}" />
            <sortItems>
                <P13nSortItem columnKey="{columnKeyModel}" operation="{operationModel}" />
            </sortItems>
        </P13nSortPanel>
        <P13nFilterPanel visible="true" type="filter"
            containerQuery="true"
            items="{
                path: '/ColumnCollection'
            }"
            filterItems="{
                path: '/FilterItems'
            }">
            <P13nItem columnKey="{path}" text="{text}" />
            <filterItems>
                <P13nFilterItem columnKey="{columnKeyModel}"
                    operation="{operationModel}" value1="{value1Model}" />
            </filterItems>
        </P13nFilterPanel>
    </panels>
</P13nDialog>
```

**Products.json** (Model)

```
{
"ColumnCollection":[
    {"text" : "ProductId", "path" : "productId", "visible" : true},
    {"text" : "Name", "path" : "name", "visible" : true},
    {"text" : "Category", "path" : "category"},
    {"text" : "SupplierName", "path" : "supplierName"},
    {"text" : "Description", "path" : "description"},
    {"text" : "WeightMeasure", "path" : "weightMeasure"},
    {"text" : "WeightUnit", "path" : "weightUnit"},
    {"text" : "Price", "path" : "price"},
    {"text" : "CurrencyCode", "path" : "currencyCode"},
    {"text" : "Status", "path" : "status"},
    {"text" : "Quantity", "path" : "quantity"},
    {"text" : "UoM", "path" : "uom"},
    {"text" : "Width", "path" : "width"},
    {"text" : "Depth", "path" : "depth"},
    {"text" : "Height", "path" : "height"},
    {"text" : "DimUnit", "path" : "dimUnit"},
    {"text" : "ProductPicUrl", "path" : "productPicUrl"}
],
"SortItems":[
    {"columnKeyModel" : "name", "operationModel" : "Descending"}
],
"FilterItems":[
    {"columnKeyModel" : "name", "operationModel" : "Contains", "value1Model" : "a"}
]}
```

Comment: Could you share some of your code? I've created one and the OK function returns the selected sort items just fine. Can you also explain a little better what you want to achieve and what is happening now, please?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I have the same issue going on where the model is not getting updated with the changes done on screen. Calling the getSorItems gets me the initial values all the time.

Answer (score 1):

this code checks all the selected sort items in the p13n dialog. Check my code sample bellow:

```
handleSortPanel: function (oEvent, table) {
        var self = this;
        var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
        var aSorters = [];
        var index = 0;
        oSource.getPanels()[2].getSortItems().forEach(function (sortItem) {
            if (sortItem.getOperation() === "Descending") {
                aSorters.push(new window.sap.ui.model.Sorter(sortItem.getColumnKey(), true));
            }
            if (sortItem.getOperation() === "Ascending") {
                aSorters.push(new window.sap.ui.model.Sorter(sortItem.getColumnKey(), false));
            }
            index += 1;
        });
        if (aSorters.length > 0) {
            self.getView().byId(table).getBinding("items").sort(aSorters);
            aSorters = [];
        }
    }
```

This code returns an array with the selected sortItems.

```
self.getView().byId(table).getBinding("items").sort(aSorters);
```

You can associate this function with the p13n dialog OK button and apply the filter to your table. Something like:

```
onOK: function (oEvent) {
        var oView = this.getView();
        var table = "tableId";

        this.handleSortPanel(oEvent, table);

        oEvent.getSource().close();
        oView.destroyDependents();
    },
```

EDIT: I found out how to get the current selected sort items. The approach is different then mine but unfortunately I don't know why.

```
oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1].getSortItems()
```

[Image of SortItems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTcmL.png)

Get position of array:

```
oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1].getSortItems()[0]
```

You can apply a foreach:

```
oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1].getSortItems().forEach(function (sortItem) { console.log(sortItem.getColumnKey()) });
```

Comment: did I miss something? I use PersonalizationDialog.fragment.xml.fragment and this.getView().addDependent(this.oPersonalizationDialog); and use the model for items, sortItems and P13nItem, P13nSortItem of the Sort Panel.

Comment: @Medera I looked at your code and I find out how to get the your current selected sort items: oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1].getSortItems(). If you want to get a specific item you can do a foreach in this list of sort items. To access the columnKey: oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1].getSortItems()[1].getColumnKey() or operation: oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1].getSortItems()[1].getOperation() (Note: I will update my post with this info)

Comment: thank you for your ideas. But my problem is that I always have only 1 item in my sort panel, even if I change it on the UI. oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1].getSortItems() // (always gives me only 1 item)

Comment: @Medera I tried again and I get 2 items with that line of code. I will update my post with an image.

Comment: ok I accidentally uploaded the version where added 2 items inside products.json  i testet 2 item, in this example you can not add a third item inside UI :  "SortItems":[
  {"columnKeyModel" : "name", "operationModel" : "Descending"},
  {"columnKeyModel" : "productPicUrl", "operationModel" : "Descending"}
 ],

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can use okay function to get what you desire, below is sample and you can enhance it

```
handleClose : function(oEvent) {
          var oSortPanel = oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[1];
          var oSortItems = oSortPanel.getAggregation("sortItems")[0];
          var oItemsObject = {"ColumnKey":oSortItems.getColumnKey(),"Operation":oSortItems.getOperation()};
          alert(JSON.stringify(oItemsObject));
            this.oPersonalizationDialog.close();

        },
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late, but maybe it will help someone else.

I found it is possible to get sort, filter and group items on P13n OK event.

This statement:

```
oEvent.getSource().getAggregation("panels")[index of your sort panel].getSortItems();
```

What I had to do is handle the add and remove events for the Sort, filter, group Panel and update items.

Example for sort events:

```
    taskAddSort: function(oEvent){
        oEvent.getSource().addSortItem(oEvent.getParameter("sortItemData"));
    },
    taskRemoveSort: function(oEvent){
        oEvent.getSource().removeSortItem(oEvent.getParameter("index"));
    },
```

And P13N dialog definition:

```
    <P13nSortPanel  type="sort"
                    containerQuery="true"
                    addSortItem=".personalization.taskAddSort"
                    removeSortItem=".personalization.taskRemoveSort"
                    sortItems="{path: '/p13nSort'}" 
                    items="{path: '/p13nItem'}">
                    <P13nItem columnKey="{columnKey}" text="{text}"/>
                    <sortItems>
                        <P13nSortItem columnKey="{columnKey}" operation="{operation}"/>
                    </sortItems>
    </P13nSortPanel>
```